# Solution to classic "Blockbuster"

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

In the UK throughout the 80's and 90's (70's too I believe!) there was a classic TV program called "Blockbuster", which had a display of hexagons in a honeycomb grid, like this (sorry for blurry pic!):

[image: picture from old Blockbuster TV game]
<sub>(source: [ukgameshows.com](http://www.ukgameshows.com/atoz/programmes/b/blockbusters/blockbusters_panel.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, there are 5 columns of letters and four rows. 1 person or team is trying to travel horizontally, one is trying to travel vertically.  You win a hexagon by answering a question, and the answer will begin with the letter displayed in that hexagon.

The winning person or team is the first to "connect a line" - note, that could be going back on itself (e.g. if it is blocked by the opposing team winning that hexagon) so there are many, many possible winning combinations.

Years ago, when I was just starting out coding, I wrote a conference game based on this puzzle (we made it alternating octagons and squares to avoid copyright infringement!) but the bit I always struggled with was the algorithm to check when a complete line was made.  The easy ones are fine, but ones going up, down, back and forth I got really stuck on!

I ended up basically coding a massive brute-force loop that still didn't catch every eventuality.  I therefore had to put a button on the conference organiser's screen to enable them to quickly declare a winner if the logic didn't detect it!  Talk about dirty hack...

Now I think back to this puzzle I had to solve, and I wonder if any of you out there would care to propose a more elegant solution?  Language agnostic of course (all including pseudocode happily accepted).

**Edit** It's fine to store your data how you want. I stuck it in an array.

Comment: Ah yes, Blockbuster... "What S is a popular question-and-answer site for programmers?"

Comment: Yes, the birthplace of such inspirational comedy as "I'd like 'P' please Bob"!...

Comment: The original game is called Hex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29 .  There are also many variants, the most interesting being Twixt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A straightforward graphics algorithm called [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) can do this.

It can also be done in a simple multi-pass approach - the blockbuster board is so small that I don't think that visiting each cell many times will have any noticeable performance impact at all - so I'd advocate this approach be tried first:

For each player, loop through all the cells; if the cell is owned by the player, and is adjacent on one if it's six sides to a cell 'marked' by this fill routine, then the cell gets marked too.  Loop again through all the cells, and again until no cells get marked to the current player.   Here's some pseudo-code:

```
for player in players:
  # those on the starting edge that the player owns get 'marked'
  for cells in cells.start_edge(player):
    if cell.owner = player:
      cell.mark = player
  do:
    count = 0
    for cell in cells:
      if cell.mark == None && cell.owner == player:
        for adjacent in cell.neighbours:
          if adjacent.mark == player
            cell.owner = player
            count += 1
            break
  while count
  for cell in cells.stop_edge(player):
     if cell.mark == player
       player won!!
```

At this point, if any of the cells on the appropriate side of the board belong to the player, the player reached that side of the board.

Comment: Flood fill looks nice.  Still trying to get my head around the *"if the cell is empty, and is adjacent to a cell 'belonging' to the player, then the cell belongs to the player"* bit!  Could you expand on that slightly?

Comment: @h4xxr: before start, white "owns" the half-filled hexes off the top of the board. Blue "owns" the hexes off the right. Then proceed as Will says - on each pass, a hex is assigned to a player if it is (a) of their colour, and (b) adjacent to a hex that player already owns. If a player owns a hex on the bottom row (white) or left column (blue), that player wins. With a bit of effort you could make the calculation iterative as each new tile is added, but that's almost certainly not worth it since a flood fill is instantaneous on a large image on modern hardware, never mind 20 cells...

Comment: Thanks onebyone, excellently summarised.  And thanks will for expanding answer

Answer (score 1):

Your problem translates to whether two nodes are connected in a graph.

- You can look at the board as a non-directed "graph". Nodes are the cells and they have edges if they are adjacent cells.
- The sides are also nodes in the graph, and those have edges to the cells adjacent to them
- Take the sub-graph of nodes you can use (including top and bottom if checking for that player)
- Check if the top and bottom are connected using DFS

Comment: It's not equivalent to Will's answer, flood fill is breadth first search.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to assign coordinates to each block.

What you can do is think of it as a simple 4x4 square grid with x coordinates in a range 0 to 4 and y from 0 to 3.

It's the responsibility of the drawing algorithm to offset the odd-numbered x cells (1 and 3) down half of a hexagonal radius so that they fit together properly.

Think about an `isAdjacent(other)` method for each cell.  In a square grid, you can reason out isAdjacent with a trivial check:  if self.x == other.x ± 1 and self.x == other.x ± 1.  There are 8 relevant combinations of -1, 0, 1 for x, -1, 0, 1 for y to be checked.

In a hexagonal grid, adjacency is a little different.  If self.y == other.y ± 1 and self.x == other.x is one part of it.  But the x adjacency depends on which column self is in.  If x is an even column (0, 2, 4), then the adjacent cell is in an odd column, which means self.y == other.y or self.y == other.y + 1.  Similarly, if x is an odd column (1, 3), then the adjacent cell is in an even column.  I'll leave it to you to work out the rest of isAdjacent.

"What about edges"?  Easy.  Include them in your `grid.get()` method.  For out-of-bounds coordinates return a special dummy cell that is never occupied.  It makes the comparison's simpler.

Okay, given `isAdjacent()` how to I find a connected path that's horizontal or vertical?

Actually, you want two forms of enumerate adjacent.  You want to create `enum_adjacent_vert(y_offset)` and `enum_adjacent_horiz(x_offset)`.  To enumerate the vertically adjacent yield three values `(self.x-1, self.y+y_offset), (self.x, self.y+y_offset), (self.x+1, self.y+y_offset)`.  To enumerate the horizontally adjacent, yield two values if self.x is in an odd column: `(self.x+x_offset, self.y), (self.x+x_offset, self.y+1)`.  If self.x is in an even column:  `(self.x+x_offset, self.y), (self.x+x_offset, self.y-1)`.

That's relatively straight forward.  Given an edge cell, you want to walk "across" or "down" the board to adjacent cells in a particular direction.

Let's say you're going from left to right (increasing x).  You want to find an adjacent cell in the `enum_adjacent_horiz` list.  To go from top to bottom (increasing y), you find an adjacent cell in the `enum_adjancent_vert` list.

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive answer.  The situations where my old algorithm failed were when the "path" say from left to right went "back on itself", eg across the bottom, then back up diagonally left, then across the top to connect.  If you're going from left to right (increasing x) will it still catch these situations?

Comment: That's the point.  If x is always increasing, you can't double back.  Your `enum_adjacent_horiz` method of a cell absolutely assure monotonic change in x.  Similarly, `enum_adjacent_horiz` absolutely guarantees monotonic change in y.